# JSON data not updating in MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to post some JSON data from my client and update my MongoDB Model. but for some reason all of my document fields are being emptied. I have tried many different manipulations of the JSON but cannot get it to insert correctly

**productDataModel.js**

```js
let mongoose = require('mongoose')

let productDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    partName:String,
    partRevision:Number,
    jobNumber:Number,
    firstApproval:String,
    checFreq:Number,
    vis_attr_description1:String,
    vis_attr_description2:String,
    vis_attr_description3:String,
    vis_attr_description4:String,
    vis_attr_description5:String,
    vis_attr_description6:String,
    vis_attr_description7:String,
    vis_attr_description8:String,
    vis_attr_description9:String,
    vis_attr_description10:String,
    //mes-attr-description
    mes_attr_description1:String,
    mes_attr_description2:String,
    mes_attr_description3:String,
    mes_attr_description4:String,
    mes_attr_description5:String,
    mes_attr_description6:String,
    mes_attr_description7:String,
    mes_attr_description8:String,
    mes_attr_description9:String,
    mes_attr_description10:String,
    //mes-min
    mes_min1:Number,
    mes_min2:Number,
    mes_min3:Number,
    mes_min4:Number,
    mes_min5:Number,
    mes_min6:Number,
    mes_min7:Number,
    mes_min8:Number,
    mes_min9:Number,
    mes_min10:Number,
    //mes-max
    mes_max2:Number,
    mes_max1:Number,
    mes_max3:Number,
    mes_max4:Number,
    mes_max5:Number,
    mes_max6:Number,
    mes_max7:Number,
    mes_max8:Number,
    mes_max9:Number,
    mes_max10:Number,
    //vis-min
    vis_min1:Number,
    vis_min2:Number,
    vis_min3:Number,
    vis_min4:Number,
    vis_min5:Number,
    vis_min6:Number,
    vis_min7:Number,
    vis_min8:Number,
    vis_min9:Number,
    vis_min10:Number,
    //vis-mes
    vis_mes1:Number,
    vis_mes2:Number,
    vis_mes3:Number,
    vis_mes4:Number,
    vis_mes5:Number,
    vis_mes6:Number,
    vis_mes7:Number,
    vis_mes8:Number,
    vis_mes9:Number,
    vis_mes10:Number,
    //vis-max
    vis_max1:Number,
    vis_max2:Number,
    vis_max3:Number,
    vis_max4:Number,
    vis_max5:Number,
    vis_max6:Number,
    vis_max7:Number,
    vis_max8:Number,
    vis_max9:Number,
    vis_max10:Number,
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('productData', productDataSchema)
```

**JSON DATA RECIEVED BY SERVER**

```js
{
  '${partName}': 'TEST',
  '${partRevision}': '${partRevision}',
  '${jobNumber}': '${jobNumber}',
  '${firstApproval}': '${firstApproval}',
  '${checkFreq}': '${checkFreq}',
  '${vis_attr_description1}': '${mes_attr_description1}',
  '${vis_mes1}': '${mes_min1}',
  '${vis_tolerance1}': '${measure1}',
  '${vis_max1}': '${mes_max1}',
  '${notes1}': '${notes1}',
  '${vis_attr_description2}': '${mes_attr_description2}',
  '${vis_mes2}': '${mes_min2}',
  '${vis_tolerance2}': '${measure2}',
  '${vis_max2}': '${mes_max2}',
  '${vis_attr_description3}': '${mes_attr_description3}',
  '${vis_mes3}': '${mes_min3}',
  '${vis_tolerance3}': '${measure3}',
  '${vis_max3}': '${mes_max3}',
  '${vis_attr_description4}': '${mes_attr_description4}',
  '${vis_mes4}': '${mes_min4}',
  '${vis_tolerance4}': '${measure4}',
  '${vis_max4}': '${mes_max4}',
  '${vis_attr_description5}': '${mes_attr_description5}',
  '${vis_mes5}': '${mes_min5}',
  '${vis_tolerance5}': '${measure5}',
  '${vis_max5}': '${mes_max5}',
  '${vis_attr_description6}': '${mes_attr_description6}',
  '${vis_mes6}': '${mes_min6}',
  '${vis_tolerance6}': '${measure6}',
  '${vis_max6}': '${mes_max6}',
  '${vis_attr_description7}': '${mes_attr_description7}',
  '${vis_mes7}': '${mes_min7}',
  '${vis_tolerance7}': '${measure7}',
  '${vis_max7}': '${mes_max7}',
  '${vis_attr_description8}': '${mes_attr_description8}',
  '${vis_mes8}': '${mes_min8}',
  '${vis_tolerance8}': '${measure8}',
  '${vis_max8}': '${mes_max8}',
  '${vis_attr_description9}': '${mes_attr_description9}',
  '${vis_mes9}': '${mes_min9}',
  '${vis_tolerance9}': '${measure9}',
  '${vis_max9}': '${mes_max9}',
  '${vis_attr_description10}': '${mes_attr_description10}',
  '${vis_mes10}': '${mes_min10}',
  '${vis_tolerance10}': '${measure10}',
  '${vis_max10}': '${mes_max10}',
  '${mes_attr_description1}': '${vis_attr_description1}',
  '${mes_min1}': '${vis_min1}',
  '${measure1}': '${vis_mes1}',
  '${mes_max1}': '${vis_max1}',
  '${notes2}': '${notes2}',
  '${mes_attr_description2}': '${vis_attr_description2}',
  '${mes_min2}': '${vis_min2}',
  '${measure2}': '${vis_mes2}',
  '${mes_max2}': '${vis_max2}',
  '${mes_attr_description3}': '${vis_attr_description3}',
  '${mes_min3}': '${vis_min3}',
  '${measure3}': '${vis_mes3}',
  '${mes_max3}': '${vis_max3}',
  '${mes_attr_description4}': '${vis_attr_description4}',
  '${mes_min4}': '${vis_min4}',
  '${measure4}': '${vis_mes4}',
  '${mes_max4}': '${vis_max4}',
  '${mes_attr_description5}': '${vis_attr_description5}',
  '${mes_min5}': '${vis_min5}',
  '${measure5}': '${vis_mes5}',
  '${mes_max5}': '${vis_max5}',
  '${mes_attr_description6}': '${vis_attr_description6}',
  '${mes_min6}': '${vis_min6}',
  '${measure6}': '${vis_mes6}',
  '${mes_max6}': '${vis_max6}',
  '${mes_attr_description7}': '${vis_attr_description7}',
  '${mes_min7}': '${vis_min7}',
  '${measure7}': '${vis_mes7}',
  '${mes_max7}': '${vis_max7}',
  '${mes_attr_description8}': '${vis_attr_description8}',
  '${mes_min8}': '${vis_min8}',
  '${measure8}': '${vis_mes8}',
  '${mes_max8}': '${vis_max8}',
  '${mes_attr_description9}': '${vis_attr_description9}',
  '${mes_min9}': '${vis_min9}',
  '${measure9}': '${vis_mes9}',
  '${mes_max9}': '${vis_max9}',
  '${mes_attr_description10}': '${vis_attr_description10}',
  '${mes_min10}': '${vis_min10}',
  '${measure10}': '${vis_mes10}',
  '${mes_max10}': '${vis_max10}'
}
```

**Server.js**

```js
app.post('/db/product/data/:product_uid',(req, res) => {
  var product_uid = req.param('product_uid');
  var Model = modelMap['productDataModel'](req.body.data)
  var data = req.body
  //get proddata id from product
  getProdDataIdFromProduct(product_uid).then(prod_data_uid => {
      var model = req.param('model');
      console.log(req.body)
      var model = new modelMap["productDataModel"](req.body.data)
      Model.replaceOne({_id: ObjectId(prod_data_uid)}, {data},  (err, res) => {
        if(err){
          console.log(err)
        }
        console.log(res)
      })
  });
})
```

the server keeps returning `{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }` but the data is being emptied could someone please point out what I am failing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Check below one

```
mongoose.model('productDataModel').replaceOne({_id: ObjectId(prod_data_uid)}, data, {upsert:true}, callback);

function callback (err, doc) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("success: ", doc);
    };
  };
```

Comment: sadly the database documents are still empty except for `_id` and `_v` I am seriously confused here

Comment: @NikHendricks could you please share parsed json **data**?

Comment: the data as the server gets it is posted above

Comment: @NikHendricks Could you please cross check, you have mapped `Model with req.body.data` but assignment of data is with request.body, isn't it with ***request.body.data***